# Passing a value with PendingIntent

Tags: android

I am using PendingIntent.  I need to pass a value.  Intent uses putExtra. Is there an equivalent for PendingIntent?  If yes, please provide sample example.  Thanks in advance.

I am using:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the extras in the original intent, i.e.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key1", "the answer");
i.putExtra("key2", 42);
...

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
```

The "inner" intent is the one your Activity will actually receive. Check the [documentation for `PendingIntent.getActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Then, in `MainActivity.onCreate()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String strValue = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("key2");
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Did that no errors.  How I do I read it when user clicks on the notification and MainActivity.class is called?  Thanks again.

Comment: First getIntent() to get the Intent, then the various `get<X>extra()` methods in the Intent class, e.g. [getIntExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: I am trying in MainActivity the following but I am getting an error:  String newString= getIntExtra("STRING_I_NEED");  what am I doing wrong?  Thanks Matiash.

Comment: @user3593666 Edited the answer with an expanded example. Hope it helps.